# PySpark unique group by on greater column

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataset as follows:

```
+-------------+-------+-----------+
|campaign_name| format|impressions|
+-------------+-------+-----------+
|   campaign_0|  video|       1500|
|   campaign_0|  video|       2000|
|   campaign_0|display|       3000|
|   campaign_1|display|       1000|
|   campaign_1|  video|       5000|
|   campaign_1|display|       8000|
+-------------+-------+-----------+
```

I want to group by `campaign_name` and **unique** `format` in a way that the `format` picked is always the greater in `sum(impressions)`. `SUM(impressions)` must account for the total of impressions of campaign.

e.g.

```
+-------------+-------+-----------+
|campaign_name| format|impressions|
+-------------+-------+-----------+
|   campaign_0|  video|       6500|
|   campaign_1|display|      14000|
+-------------+-------+-----------+
```

Comment: for group 1 (`campaign_0`), `video` is selected because `video` appears twice or because the sum of video is more than display ?, also what happens when you have 3 values in a group?

Comment: `video` is selected because it's sum is greater. in the case of 3+ values the logic must be the same, the value picked must have the greater sum.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with 2 window functions:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
w1 = Window.partitionBy("campaign_name","format")
w2 = Window.partitionBy("campaign_name")

(df.withColumn("sum_in_grp", F.sum("impressions").over(w1))
   .withColumn("Max_in_grp",F.max("sum_in_grp").over(w2))
   .withColumn("impressions",F.sum("impressions").over(w2))
   .filter(F.col("sum_in_grp")==F.col("Max_in_grp")).dropDuplicates()
   .select(*df.columns).orderBy("campaign_name")).show()
```

---

```
+-------------+-------+-----------+
|campaign_name| format|impressions|
+-------------+-------+-----------+
|   campaign_0|  video|       6500|
|   campaign_1|display|      14000|
+-------------+-------+-----------+
```